# React scheduler's `unstable_runWithPriority` doesn't use `priority` in any way

Tags: reactjs, scheduler, react-fiber

I ran a profiler on the following code:

```
function App() {
  const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0);
  return <div>
    <div>{counter}</div>
    <button onClick={(e) => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Inc</button>
  </div>
}
```

[image]
Which is pretty standard, what's interesting is the `unstable_runWithPriority` [function](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8e5adfbd7e605bda9c5e96c10e015b3dc0df688e/packages/scheduler/src/Scheduler.js#L217).
It takes priority as a parameter but doesn't schedule anything, instead it calls the event handler.

Regardless of what the priority is, it just runs it all the same. Can someone elaborate the necessity of this function?

Shouldn't there be some sort of task or a microtask scheduled based on priority?

Answer (score 0):

It sets `currentPriorityLevel` (a global variable which is used by other functions in the chain) to given priority. Runs the task and returns `currentPriorityLevel` back to its original value.

Comment: Could you point that on the code? I dont think I saw that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use your demo to illustrate.

1. onClick => currentPriorityLevel = UserBlockingPriority
2. setCounter(eventHandler in runWithPriority) => `createUpdate(eventTime, lane, suspenseConfig)`
3. the lane comes from `requestUpdateLane(fiber, suspenseConfig)`
4. so the lane is come from the currentPriorityLevel;

```
    function requestUpdateLane(
      fiber: Fiber,
      suspenseConfig: SuspenseConfig | null,
    ): Lane {
      const schedulerPriority = getCurrentPriorityLevel();
      let lane;
      if (
        (executionContext & DiscreteEventContext) !== NoContext &&
        schedulerPriority === UserBlockingSchedulerPriority
      ) {
        lane = findUpdateLane(InputDiscreteLanePriority, currentEventWipLanes);
      } else {
        const schedulerLanePriority = schedulerPriorityToLanePriority(
          schedulerPriority,
        );
        lane = findUpdateLane(schedulerLanePriority, currentEventWipLanes);
      }
      return lane;
    }
```